# PC based wireless audio receiver (...bluetooth?)

Tags: audio, bluetooth, desktop-computer, speakers

The idea: Having one stationary PC+speakers able to receive and play audio from any mobile devices that come and go (android / laptops). One at a time, just have the PC work as remote speakers.

My first thought was bluetooth - get the stationary PC act as bluetooth speakers. That could be idiot-proof, as most devices should work with something that poses as bluetooth audio speaker.
Some sucess there (Win7 + android works kinda cool), but no luck getting laptop Win system recognize the desktop as remote speakers.

Not so much luck with linux based OS's, got the Bluetooth working but couldn't get it recognized as audio source in Ubuntu 14.04 (quite possibly due to my lack of linux skills)
Found a lot of guides how to get this done on older ubuntu releases (10-12), not tried those yet.

Through wifi - found some options, not tried them yet - to my understanding they they will require special app on both sides (not a problem on desktop side, not so comfortable on multiple mobile devices)

Any tips how to realize this? The stationary PC is normal desktop, able to run any almost any OS. Bluetooth through Asus BT400.

Or just ditch the idea, get a solo bluetooth reciever for the speakers and go on with that.
Thanks for any time taken to read this and answer.

Comment: I think you should either get a standalone Bluetooth receiver for the speakers or you should get a Chromecast Audio.